# jQuery Load And Ajax Forms Not Working Together

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've created a news system, where i should be able to edit articles dynamically without redirect, from a modal. Also, i should be able to delete and create articles.

When something is changed, jQuery Load is called, but the problem is when i have to edit the loaded content.

```
    $("#toolbox-items").load('inc-toolbox');
```

The above code loads the articles (the file is called inc-toolbox on purpose and works fine).

```
    $(function () {
        $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var clicked = document.activeElement.getAttribute('name');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'process-toolbox',
                data: $(this).serialize() + "&" + clicked + "=success",
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#toolbox-items").load('inc-toolbox');
                    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

But, when ever something has to be edited or deleted, the whole page reloads and nothing changes, although i'm still able to add things.

The add-button is not loaded dynamically from the script, but is in there from the start.

What in the world might the problem be?

Comment: Most likely means you are not binding your event to the element. Is the form  within `#toolbox-items` ?

Comment: The form(s) for editing the elements is, yes, the form for adding elements is not though.

Comment: Look at the following example relating to [binding event handlers to dynamically created elements](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#event-propagation). Based on your comment, it seems you want `$(document).on('submit', 'form', ...);` instead of `$('form').on('submit', ...)`.

Comment: Works like a charm, if you want to create a answer i'll mark it as approved.

Comment: Look at Adrian's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try code like this

```
  $(function () {
        $(document).on('submit','form', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var clicked = document.activeElement.getAttribute('name');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'process-toolbox',
                data: $(this).serialize() + "&" + clicked + "=success",
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#toolbox-items").load('inc-toolbox');
                    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```